# finding the sum of columns in 2d arrays c++

Tags: c++, arrays

How do I find the sum of columns? I only know how to find the sum of rows and
the overall total

Sorry I'm still a newbie programmer freshmen in college

Thanks to anyone who can help me!

Here is my Code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        int row, column, rowsum=0, total=0, number1=1, number2=1;
        int rowcol[5][5];
        {
            for (row = 0; row < 5; row++)
            {
                for (column = 0; column < 5; column++)
            {
                cout << "Enter employee no." << number1 << " salary: ";
                cin >> rowcol[row][column];
            }
            number1 = number1 + 1;
            }

            for (row = 0; row < 5; row++)
            {
                rowsum = 0;
                for (column = 0; column < 5; column++)
                {
                    rowsum = rowsum + rowcol[row][column];
                }
                cout << "Total salary of employee no." << number2 << ": " << rowsum << endl;
                number2 = number2 + 1;  
            }

            for (row = 0; row < 5; row++) 
            {
                for (column = 0; column < 5; column++)
                {
                    total = total + rowcol[row][column];
                }
            }
            cout << "Total salary of all employees: " << total;
        }
        system("pause>0");  
        return 0;   
    }
```

Comment: Hint, Inverting your loops should be an interesting ponder.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks a lot! I just switched the array[row][col] to array[col][row] and i got it!

Comment: Close, ideally you should invert the for-loops, not the indexes. it worked for you because your matrix is reflexive. If it were off (5x6, 2x4, etc) you would be invoking *undefined behavior*. Rather than for-rows outside, for-columns inside, just do for-columns outside, for-rows inside, keeping everything else as it was.